# Site.createPortalUser is unable to assign a profileId

Tags: lightning-web-components, controller, self-registration

```
public with sharing class RegisterModalController {
    
    public class CustomException extends Exception {}

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void register(String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        String defaultAccountId;
        String ProfileId;
        String userId;
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

        accounts = [    SELECT Id 
                        FROM Account 
                        WHERE Name LIKE 'Default%'  
                        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC 
                        LIMIT 1];

        ProfileId = [   SELECT Id 
                        FROM Profile 
                        WHERE Name='Custom Partner Community User' 
                        LIMIT 1].id;

        
        if(accounts.isEmpty()) {
            throw new CustomException('Default Account not found');
        }

        Contact con = new Contact();
        con.FirstName = firstName;
        con.LastName = lastName;
        con.Email = email;
        con.AccountId = defaultAccountId;
        insert con;

        defaultAccountId = accounts[0].Id;

        User user = new User();
        user.Username = email.split('@')[0] + '.some.user';
        user.Email = email;
        user.FirstName = firstName;
        user.LastName = lastName;
        user.ProfileId = profileId;
        user.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
        user.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
        user.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
        user.contactId = con.Id;
        user.CommunityNickname = System.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

        try{
            // User siteUser = createUser(email, firstName, lastName, profileId);
            userId = Site.createPortalUser(user, defaultAccountId, password, true);
        } catch(CustomException e) {
            throw new CustomException('Error creating user: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I am aware of the standard self register controller aura component and it's selfRegister class, but I can't use them for this task.

I'm trying to create an LWC for self registration of partner users. the LWC is coming along fine but the controller has thrown me a blocker.

when I create the user I am unable to assign a profileId. I get an error that says the field is not writable. I can't find anywhere in salesforce to make that field writable, or maybe I just don't know where to look. I also can't tell for sure if it's not a permissions thing, and the field is just not writable for everyone, but I feel like that doesn't make any sense. I also can't create the user without the profile Id.

this profileId thing is driving me nuts. I can't figure it out.

I would appreciate any help in clearing this blocker.

Comment: The documentation is not entirely clear on this, but you should use createExternalUser instead of createPortalUser.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I did end up using the create external user method, and I got it to create the user. I read some documentation that mentioned the difference between external and portal was that external creates customer users, and portal creates partner users, but that ended up being wrong. 

I also couldn't log in with the users that were created. I'm still trying to figure out why that is.